# How can I use Class in a namespace?

Tags: php

I have a `Class.php` file and I am trying to use it in another file.

```
use App\Class;
```

However, I get this error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'Class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Is there any way to use Class in my namespace or do I have to rename it?

Answer (score 1):

[You can't use reserved words as class names!](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class) It is anyway a bad idea, because you should use a meaningful name for it - you will forget what it was for one day.

Just in case you didn't want to use the class "Class" - because that is what `use App\Class` [is gonna try](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php), you can include files using `include('Class.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a class named `Class` inside that file? the `use` statement is for loading classes not "just" a file.

anyway you can't use `Class` as a class name or namespace segment as it's a [reserved word](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php)

Comment: Yes there is a class named Class.

Comment: to be sure i tested it: you can't have a class named `Class`, it will raise a `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'Class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in …`